# Perl - Hash of Arrays across Threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, hash, multidimensional-array

I’m a beginner in Perl but have to develop some script to parse TCP-dump.
Here it is (I truncated it and leave the relevant code only):

I get the following error:
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at TestThread1.pl line 16,
This is because of this string:
%input = (%input, $fix_ClOrdID => [$FrameTime_epoch,$fix_MsgType]);

From many similar topics I’ve read I understand that I cannot share a nested references using threads::shared. And I also found some workaround how to do it. But due to lack of experience I can’t apply examples for my case.

Could you please advise how to fix my script to make it work!

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
my %input:shared = ();
threads->new(\&FixParser)->detach();

sub FixParser{  
 open(InFile, 'myFix.dmp') || die;
 while(InFile>){
  ($FrameTime_epoch,$fix_MsgType,$fix_ClOrdID) = split(';',);
  if(exists($input{$fix_ClOrdID})){
   $ExecDelay=$FrameTime_epoch-$input{$fix_ClOrdID}[0];
   print "MsgType: $input{$fix_ClOrdID}[1] ExecDelay: $ExecDelay us\n";
   delete($input{$fix_ClOrdID});
  }
  else{
   %input = (%input, $fix_ClOrdID => [$FrameTime_epoch,$fix_MsgType]);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste the actual code from your application?  I can't help but notice you didn't `use strict; use warnings;`, and the code as listed wouldn't compile.  For example, I'm just eyeballing it but this line `while(InFile>)` should say `while(<InFile>)`.  Try adding `use strict; use warnings;` and fix those errors.  If there's still a problem you should ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock your shared variable and clone structure before adding to hash,

```
sub FixParser {  
  open(my $InFile, "<", 'myFix.dmp') || die $!;
  while(<$InFile>) {

    ADVISORY_LOCK: {
      lock(%input);
      # ..
      if(exists($input{$fix_ClOrdID})) {
        # ..
      }
      else{
       # %input = (%input, $fix_ClOrdID => [$FrameTime_epoch,$fix_MsgType]);
       $input{ $fix_ClOrdID } = threads::shared::shared_clone( [$FrameTime_epoch,$fix_MsgType] );
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It seems working!
But this $input{ $fix_ClOrdID } = threads::shared::shared_clone( [$FrameTime_epoch,$fix_MsgType] );
just replaces the last entry of hash but I need to add entries into %input..